# ReactJS: reading value from session in Component

Tags: node.js, session, express, reactjs

What is the common way in React to read value stored in session on server side (express) in React Component?

I have an auth method that stores token in session (on server). For every next action that require an auth token, i can get it on server side, but i would need to have my UI look different for authorized and non-authorized users. How could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you interact with your server through an API but what you're suggesting is not something you'd want to do. The authentication is usually done on a per-route basis, and the UI would send a key that maybe gets stored in local storage or as a cookie.

For example, you could have all your routes authenticate by requiring the user's "auth cookie". If it is missing, the user is redirected to "sign in" after which the server sends back the auth key and the UI stores it. The UI can then send it with each request using `credentials: 'include'`.

This is only one of many solutions out there, not really related to React at all but more broadly to UIs. Hopefully this will help your search!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a value from session storage:

```
const val1 = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
const val2 = sessionStorage.getItem("useremail");
```